# Migrate projects thymeleaf pages to Angular gradually

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, architecture, thymeleaf

I need to switch an existing Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application gradually to a Spring Boot + Angular application. Part of the webapp to be serverside rendered and parts of it to be an angular application.

What I've come up with so far:

1. Create a standard angular application and run it with ng serve
2. For each page I want to switch to angular, I take the Thymeleaf template, insert the corresponding `<app-angular-component>` tag and add the `<script src="">` tags to point to main.js / runtime.js. In the angular-component I can program like a normal angular app.
3. Once every page is migrated, routing logic needs to be added to Angular for it to be a full fledged app on its own.

Is this valid approach to migrating away from Thymeleaf or do you have better approaches to do this ?

Comment: Off topic, but what is the reason for the move? Are there things you want to do that are not possible with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Just the general advantages a SPA has to server side rendered pages. And as developers to be able to code/test in a proper framework rather than plain typescript/javascript.